# Programmatically stop an agent

Tags: ajax, lotus-domino

In a web page, i start an FTSearch using an agent called via ajax.

Is there a way to programmatically stop this agent (for example, using a button)?

Comment: In my experience, an FTSearch should end within 2-3 seconds, on the condition that the database is FT indexed. I wonder why you ask the question. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: It depends on how much documents your database contains. My goal would be to stop the agent that perform the FTSearch when desired.

Comment: Why do you want to stop the agent? How long does it take the agent to finish its job? If there is only one FTSearch in it, it should take no longer than 3 seconds to search your database (irrespective of the number of documents in the database). Does the agent do many other things? Can't you optimise that, if it takes too long?

Answer (score 2):

Not really. You could programmatically restart the http task... 
There's a server setting which defines a timeout for webagents, which should be set.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a check to your code, testing an environment variable for its value... For example, use this (in pseudo-code):

```
count= count + 1
if count modulo 100 = 0 then // only once per 100 docs
    if getEnvironmentVar("STOP_MY_AGENT")=1 then
        exit
    fi
fi
```

And then you need some button to set the environment variable. Make sure that in both cases you use the same environment, i.e. the same notes.ini file!